# Android crash after splash screen

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

I'm building an app with .NET MAUI Hybrid and I wanted to roll out a new test version of the app on both iOS and Android. All previously test versions have worked just fine but now on Android (works on iOS) an error occurs after the splash screen, the app itself doesn't crash but I get yellow-ish popup that blazor applications gives you when an error has occurred.

I've generated a bug report via settings on the phone but it didn't really tell me much. I did find a small stacktrace but my google attempts were fruitless.

```
Exceptions thrown (exception_count, class_name):
      22 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       2 java.lang.SecurityException
       2 android.os.ParcelableException
```

I'm unsure if it's my code that's the problem here since it works perfectly whilst debugging on a physical device. I did add [Community Toolkit MAUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui/2.0.0) to the project during this iteration, however currently it's unused on Android, still included in the build but not used.

Comment: I would manually delete app from device or emulator. Delete .bin and .obj folders. These steps make sure your next build and run are completely clean. Also consider factory reset of emulator. Another test is to create a blank "landing page" that your app starts on. Not a Blazor page, just an empty Maui ContentPage. This way, you'll know that the app startup is okay. In that page's OnAppearing, add a code line to go to your Blazor page. Which you can comment out as a test. I use a simple "landing page" in my apps, to avoid any possibility of exceeding OS app startup timeout.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the response but I'm afraid none of them worked. I did however notice something. If do a fresh install of the new test version, the crash occurs but if I download the most recent working test version and simply update the app to the newer test version, the crash does not occur...

Comment: It had to do with a cached file not being generated on a fresh install on the newer test version. It's all good now. Thanks again for your response! :)

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Did you fix it with some VS menu option, or by manually deleting files somewhere? Would like to know the exact step that fixed it, for future reference.

Comment: It was a custom config that's being loaded in during start-up of the app, so it had nothing to do with VS/MAUI/dotnet, just a silly mistake by me.